Keras CNN - Training Image Classification Model with Variable Image Sizes
I'm currently working on constructing an image classification model with Keras. The challenge I'm facing relates to the variable sizes of the images in my dataset. My goal is to build a model that can effectively classify images while preserving their original sizes to avoid distortions. So I'm encountering an issue while training an image classification model with Keras. The architecture of my model allows for variable input image dimensions, specified as input_shape=(None, None, 3), to preserve the original sizes of the images.
Create the model
`model = Sequential()
Input layers
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(None, None, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation="relu"))
Add GlobalMaxPooling2D`
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling2D())
Add activation softmax`
model.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))
This part working but when it's coming to train the model, I am encountering an issue.
steps = 50 epochs = 25
reshape input data to match tensorflow iteration order
x_train = []
for img in df['Image']:
`x_train.append(img.array.transpose(1,2,0))`

training data gen (data agumentation)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
gen = train_datagen.flow(np.asarray(x_train), df['ClassIndex'])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(gen, steps_per_epoch=steps, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
I have got this error
Execute failed: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (11, 1) 
I think this error was about trying to converting the images into NumPy arrays and storing them in a list, But it can't work with the inconsistent dimensions of the images.
So I'm seeking guidance on how to handle this issue effectively.
Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Dimension of the data you passed to Conv2D layer caused you have this error.
Conv2D layer generally want data with this format: (batch_size, height, width, channels).
 But your data shape is (11, 1).  Reshaping x_train might be useful.

Thank you for your response and for offering your help. Unfortunately, the issue you mentioned is exactly what I've been struggling with. My images have varying dimensions, and the array method expects fixed sizes. I've been stuck on this problem for days now, and I haven't been able to find a solution in other posts, as they usually focus on creating the model rather than preparing the images. If you have any suggestions or insights on how to handle variable-sized images in the preprocessing stage, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you again for your assistance!

I am suggesting that you should resize all the images from your dataset to a particular size by resizing them all. There are two approaches for that. First, you can do it as a preprocessing task and I'm offering you read this article (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize).
Second, you can add resizing layer to your model. So the model itself would resize all the images before doing any feature extracting process. Read this article (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Resizing).

I hope you can finally get over with this problem. Please don't hesitate if you are coming up with new questions.
